# Parsing a json file in python create difficulties

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to parse a json file in python. I don't know the content of the file. I downloaded this file from a website in json format.

As per my knowledge to parse a json file we need this code

```
import json

sourcefile=open("News_Category_Dataset_v2.json","r")
json_data=json.load(sourcefile)

print (json_data)
```

But I got this error as describe below. jsonparse.py is my file name which is save in my computer d:/algorithm

D:\python\envs\algorithms\python.exe D:/algorithms/jsonparse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:/algorithms/jsonparse.py", line 4, in <module>
json_data=json.load(sourcefile)

File "D:\python\envs\algorithms\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File "D:\python\envs\algorithms\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "D:\python\envs\algorithms\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 366)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How could I fix the problem?

Comment: Your file is not valid JSON. Looking at the position of the problem, it might be JSON Lines where every line is a JSON object. It that possible?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your json file?

Comment: @Nithin This json file downloaded. So I don't know it's content. How could I open a json file without parse it in python. My computer does not have any app which open json file.

Comment: @KlausD. This file downloaded from kaggle. All I have to know about this file is About this file
**The file contains 202,372 records.** Each json record contains following attributes:

**category**: Category article belongs to

**headline**: Headline of the article

**authors**: Person authored the article

**link**: Link to the post

**short_description**: Short description of the article

**date**: Date the article was published

Comment: The problem is within the syntax of the file. It is not helpful to describe the content. And you can open a JSON file with every working text editor.

Comment: I managed to find your the json file. It is not in a proper json format.
The following code snippet might help you

import json
json_list = []
for i in open('test.json'):
    json_line = json.loads(i)
    json_list.append(json_line)
print(json_list)

Comment: `json` file can be opened in any editor.

Comment: Thanks Nithin for your help, It work well.Can you please explain the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is not json. but it has lines where each one of them is json.

This snippet should help you

```
import json

json_list = []
for i in open('test.json'):
    json_line = json.loads(i)
    json_list.append(json_line)
print(json_list)
```